# How to get the closing price of the highest/lowest candle?

Tags: pine-script, trading

I have some coding background and usually I'd be able to solve this but I looked through the forums and Google and found no solution to this. Basically, I want the output from highestbars() or lowestbars() and put it in close[]. There is no quick solution for this because highestbars()/lowestbars() outputs datatype Series[integer] while 'close' takes in integer.

I've tried using a for loop to go through the same amount of candlesticks and check for highest/lowest prices but it doesn't work. I tried to just output highest and lowest to compare it with highest() and lowest() but it's not even close.

Any help would be appreciated since I've been stuck on this.

```
//@version=4
study("Highest and Lowest Zones", overlay=true)

float high_close = close[12]
float last_close_high = high_close
int high_bar = highestbars(64)[12]

high1 = highest(64)[12]
low1 = lowest(64)[12]

for i = 0 to 64
    closeHigh = (high[i+13] > high[i+12])
    high_close := closeHigh ? close[i]: last_close_high
    last_close_high := high_close

p1 = plot(high1, title="High", color=color.red)
p2 = plot(high_close, title="Low", color=color.red)
fill(p1, p2)

float low_close = close[12]
float last_close_low = low_close

for i = 0 to 64
    closeLow = (low[i+13] > low[i+12])
    low_close := closeLow ? close[i+13]: last_close_low
    last_close_low := low_close

p3 = plot(low1, title="High", color=color.green)
p4 = plot(low_close, title="Low", color=color.green)
fill(p3, p4)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
plot(close[0-highestbars(10)])
```